# postfix on mac (snow leopard) / php mail() won't work (Operation timed out...)

Tags: php, email, port, postfix-mta

After hours and hours of research on this (it does appear to be quite an issue)... it still won't work.

I already tried with changes to main.cf, master.cf, php.ini, org.postfix.master...

For main.cf it was suggested to set "myhostname = host.domain.tld" to something one has control over, which I don't. Everything I tried telnetting to (e.g. telnet some-IP 25) refused to answer (except localhost, which doesn't help much.

I've also uncommented the line

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

In master.cf, which was meant to enable other ports (or another port) besides 25 - but in my mail.log file there are still entries like the following (I have edited the name of the mailserver):

```
Oct 11 14:56:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: E8E0A46D8A7: from=<_www@host.domain.ch>, size=543, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 14:56:36 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2168]: connect to mail.domain.ch[80.74.142.100]:25: Operation timed out
```

So, it does try to use port 25 and I can't figure out how to prevent (or rather change) that.

I also tried it with my local firewall switched off (just to make sure it wasn't that) - this didn't change anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

### Following is my main.cf

```
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 0034146BB27: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 0357B46D316: from=, size=543, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 2367D46D8F3: from=, size=543, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 25DC646C0CC: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 2D08046D084: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 380CB468328: from=, size=1024, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 3D87246BE1D: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 4092446D0D5: from=, size=544, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 425C546D10B: from=, size=544, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 4D2FE46D4FB: from=, size=543, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 5E45B46BDA1: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 5F20946BE63: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 69CB746D16A: from=, size=542, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 78A9746BDF1: from=, size=2790, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 7EEF24681C7: from=, size=1003, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 8156D46D0C3: from=, size=544, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 81B9346BDF5: from=, size=2788, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 83D3146BDF7: from=, size=2791, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 84B4A46BBC8: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 8594046BDF8: from=, size=2790, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: 85FA546D241: from=, size=542, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: B3D5C46D48C: from=, size=543, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: B3E2F46BC75: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: C96AD46BE3B: from=, size=554, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: D99D646BAC0: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: E0D5A468502: from=, size=1024, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/qmgr[2123]: E327946BD2F: from=, size=568, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 11 15:11:36 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2202]: connect to mail.recipients-domain.ch[80.74.142.100]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:36 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2203]: connect to mail.recipients-domain.ch[80.74.142.100]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:36 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2204]: connect to mail.recipients-domain.ch[80.74.142.100]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:36 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2205]: connect to mail.recipients-domain.ch[80.74.142.100]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:36 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2206]: connect to mail.recipients-domain.ch[80.74.142.100]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:36 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2207]: connect to jay.hsz-t.ch[193.5.54.121]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:36 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2209]: connect to jay.hsz-t.ch[193.5.54.121]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:37 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2213]: connect to jay.hsz-t.ch[193.5.54.121]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:37 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2208]: connect to barracuda.in2net.com[65.61.198.253]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:37 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2212]: connect to barracuda.in2net.com[65.61.198.253]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:37 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2210]: connect to barracuda.in2net.com[65.61.198.253]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:11:37 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2211]: connect to barracuda.in2net.com[65.61.198.253]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2202]: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2203]: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2204]: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2205]: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2206]: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2202]: 0034146BB27: to=, relay=none, delay=77166, delays=77106/0.06/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2203]: 0357B46D316: to=, relay=none, delay=46901, delays=46841/0.03/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2207]: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2204]: 2367D46D8F3: to=, relay=none, delay=9419, delays=9359/0.03/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2205]: 25DC646C0CC: to=, relay=none, delay=69083, delays=69023/0.03/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2206]: 2D08046D084: to=, relay=none, delay=57881, delays=57821/0.03/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2207]: 380CB468328: to=, relay=none, delay=220408, delays=220348/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2221]: 3D87246BE1D: to=, relay=none, delay=69826, delays=69766/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2221]: 4092446D0D5: to=, relay=none, delay=57542, delays=57482/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2221]: 425C546D10B: to=, relay=none, delay=57374, delays=57314/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2221]: 4D2FE46D4FB: to=, relay=none, delay=45191, delays=45131/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2221]: 5E45B46BDA1: to=, relay=none, delay=71715, delays=71654/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2221]: 69CB746D16A: to=, relay=none, delay=57113, delays=57053/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2222]: 5F20946BE63: to=, relay=none, delay=69372, delays=69311/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2221]: 8156D46D0C3: to=, relay=none, delay=57678, delays=57618/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2222]: 84B4A46BBC8: to=, relay=none, delay=75648, delays=75588/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2221]: 85FA546D241: to=, relay=none, delay=50808, delays=50748/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2222]: B3D5C46D48C: to=, relay=none, delay=46259, delays=46199/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2222]: D99D646BAC0: to=, relay=none, delay=77430, delays=77370/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2222]: E327946BD2F: to=, relay=none, delay=72007, delays=71947/60/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2221]: B3E2F46BC75: to=, relay=none, delay=74076, delays=74016/60/0/0.01, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/error[2223]: C96AD46BE3B: to=, relay=none, delay=69567, delays=69507/60/0/0.01, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2209]: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:12:06 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2209]: 7EEF24681C7: to=, relay=none, delay=220835, delays=220775/0.01/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
Oct 11 15:12:07 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2213]: connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out
Oct 11 15:12:07 my-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[2213]: E0D5A468502: to=, relay=none, delay=218862, delays=218802/0.03/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to romulus.metanet.ch[80.74.138.2]:25: Operation timed out)
```

Thank you very much for your time!!!

r.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your isp is blocking port 25 outbound (mine does).

try putting this in your main.cf:

```
relayhost=smtp.gmail.com:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options=
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
```

then create a file:
/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
with something like this in it:

```
smtp.gmail.com:587 outboundgmailaccount@gmail.com:password
```

and run:
sudo postmap sasl_passwd

I created a gmail account just for sending emails from my computer, so I didn't have to leave my main email account password in plain text in a file on my computer, but you could use your main gmail account as well if you wanted to.

Comment: Does this still work for you? I'm getting `certificate verification failed`